# Limits of processing data on the client vs. processing data on the server

Tags: postgresql, performance, electron, vuex

For a desktop App (ERP like functionality) I'm and wondering what would be wiser to do.

Assuming that both machines are equal in performance and the server has to deal with max. 5-10 clients and no other obligations. Is it better to load all data initially (~20.000 objects) and do filtering, sorting etc. on the client (electron) or is it better to do the processing on the backend (golang + postgres) over Axios. The user interface should be as snappy as possible but also get the data as fast as possible.

A costly operation is filtering 15.000 Objects by a reference ID. (e.g. a client can have several orders)

So objects that belong to a "parent object" are displayed by querying all those objects by a parentID.

Is there a general answer to what would be more performant, or a better choice here? Doing some assumptions, like a latency of 5ms in the network + 20ms for the API + a couple for filling the store.
At which data size will this operation be slower on the frontend or completely unsustainable?

If it's not a performance problem, are there other reasons I would want to do this on the server?

Edit: Client and Server are on the same local network

Answer (score 0):

You specifically mention an ERP-like software. For such software you have to carefully consider the value of consistency:

#### Will your software need to show the same data for all clients?

If the answer to this is yes, then the simplest implementation is to do data processing on the server which informs all clients of changing data.

If the answer to this is no, then you should be fine doing most processing on the client software.

There are of course ways to do most of your processing on the client yet still have consistency but they will add complexity to your overall design. One implementation is to broadcast changes on one client to all other clients. This is the architecture behind most multiplayer online games.

Another way to tackle this is implemented by git: the data on all clients are different from each other but there are ways to synchronize each client data with the server thus achieving eventual consistency.

Another consideration you have to think about is the size of your data:

#### Will downloading all the data from the server take more than a few seconds?

If downloading all data from the server takes too long then the UI will be essentially unresponsive when starting.

Comment: The frontend clients that receive the big chunks of data would be on the same local network as the server. 
The other external clients would make use of small API calls and don't need to do a lot of processing.

For consistency I have two approaches in mind. One is checking if the data has been updated before it's submitted, the other one is having live updates. Not sure if I will be able to implement that however. (SSE?, websockets?)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Don't think about it in terms of how chunk size. Think about it in terms of time. Does loading all the data take a few seconds? If so it's too big. If not it's just right. One example I've seen before is an actual ERP system that has been running for 8 years. The total data size is around 60GB which is not feasible to download onto client - forget transfer time (which is a few hours on LAN), most clients don't have that much RAM to spare. I cannot answer such design questions for you but only give you hints on what to think about. You will need to figure out the best approach for your software

Comment: Agreed. 20.000-30.000 "small" objects should be the amount of data generated every 12 months at which point older data will not be loaded into the client anymore at initialization. 60gb sounds more like the size of a giant DB )) It depends on the use case of course, for this data of the past 12 months is more than sufficient for 98% of the daily work.

One thing I don't understand is why the boot time of several seconds would be a problem? Ideally, it happens only once. I see that this would absolutely require broadcasting of micro updates to avoid conflicts. Any good book on this topic?

Comment: Where I'm from taxes can be audited up to 7 years after the fact therefore the 8 years of data especially sales and purchase data only has one redundant year. It is uncommon but not completely out of the ordinary for users to pull data from several years back.

Comment: Yes, this still could be solved in an additional API call by year when necessary, just not at initialization. If rarer use-cases come with a slight performance penalty it should be ok. As I see it now the most difficult part would be concurrency as you mention. Either broadcasting or pinging the server every couple of seconds to get only updated data and not the whole set would be a possibility. But it does complicate the client.